# Sending multiple emails from Excel

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a workbook that has 7 worksheets.  I have the below vba to send an email once a value is met on a particular sheet.

Each sheet has a different value and a different attachment to be sent.  How do I add a code for each sheet so the email is sent?

Thanks in advance

Set as General (Declarations)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M4:M368"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 3500 Then
            Call Fuel_LevelW03
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

followed by a module
General Fuel_LevelW03

```
Sub Fuel_LevelW03()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please order fuel as attached." & vbNewLine & _
              "" & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & _
              ""

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = "email address"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Fuel Order W03"
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add ("H:\Fuel Order Sheets\Glen Eden W03 Pump Station.xlsx")
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The _Change event is per worksheet, so you will need to code traps at that level. You can generalize the module to accept parameters from the various worksheet-level calls.

Comment: Thanks Andy. So do I create a change event for each worksheet changing the target value and the call "name". How do I generalize the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you try to "tell the method" a bit about what the `Target.Value` was. Just pass the parameter to the function like this :

```
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    If Target.Value < 3500 Then
        Call Fuel_LevelW03( Sh.Name, Target.Value )
    End If
End If
```

and change the function's name with this one :

```
Fuel_LevelW03( sheetName as String, targetValue as String )
                                                   'Change String to appropriate type
```

---

**EDIT2 :** I changed the code around a bit, if you need any help let me know.

**EDIT :** Ok, here's how you solve this. Inside the "ThisWorkbook" code object (underneath the sheet code objects, on the left side of the code editor), paste this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M4:M368"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 3500 Then
            Call Fuel_LevelW03( Sh.Name )
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Fuel_LevelW03( sheetName as String )
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    On Error Resume Next

    If sheetName = "Sheet1" Then 'Replace Sheet1 with the name of your worksheet

        strbody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please order fuel as attached." & vbNewLine & _
              "" & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & _
              "STRING BODY1"

        With OutMail
            .To = "email address"
            .CC = "email address"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Fuel Order W03"
            .Body = strbody
            .Attachments.Add ("H:\Fuel Order Sheets\Glen Eden W03 Pump Station.xlsx")
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

    ElseIf sheetName = "Sheet2" Then 'Replace Sheet2 with the name of the next sheet and 

        'Put the same content as the first IF statement, but adapted to "Sheet2"

    ElseIf sheetName = "Sheet3" Then 'Replace Sheet3 with the name of the next sheet and 

        'Put the same content as the first IF statement, but adapted to "Sheet3"

    ElseIf sheetName = "Sheet4" Then 'Replace Sheet4 with the name of the next sheet and 

        'Put the same content as the first IF statement, but adapted to "Sheet4"

    'ElseIf ............. (So on, so forth)


    End If

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can add as many `ElseIf`'s as you want (one for each sheet)

---

Am pretty sure this is what you need, although am not sure.

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then

    'Do something specific to "Sheet1"

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Then

    'Do something specific to "Sheet2"

    'And so on so forth...

End If
```

You have a button to that macro in each sheet, and depending on the sheet calling the macro, you want a different e-mail to be sent, right? Then this will do it. You can add as many `ElseIf`'s as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit unsure, as I'm not really an expert at this.  The target value for each worksheet is a different figure, also, the attachment that needs to be sent is different.  I don't have a button to run the macro, as soon as the value went under the target value, it automatically sent the email.  This code works perfectly for the one sheet, I just need to replicate it for the other worksheets, amending the target value and attachment. I'm very much a novice when it comes to coding.

Comment: Is it possible to add in "the target value" the worksheet name?